# Permutation test and p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, permutation-test

I construct a permutation test in order to see If two samples come from the same distribution or not. I have two vectors $x,y$ that hold values of sampled values from two populations and the test statistics $mean(x)−mean(y)$. I am given a p-value and the test and I need to decide whether to reject or accept $H_0$. How can I use p value to make a decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you haven't tested whether they are from the same distribution, but only whether they have the same mean. Two distributions could be very different but have the same mean.

Second, you haven't given the exact way you constructed the permutation test, so I can't be 100% certain, but (unless something is very odd) you would reject $H_0$ if the p value was small; the most common cutoff is 0.05